# Is "a major overhaul" pleonasm?

Tags: meaning, semantics, pleonasms

Is it correct to say "a major overhaul", or the meaning of "major" is actually included in the meaning of "overhaul", thus a combination of these two words is a pleonasm?

Comment: I don't think *"minor overhaul"* is used very often, so in that sense *"major overhaul"* is a pleonasm. However, one can imagine gradations of overhaul, e.g. *an overhaul, a major overhaul, a complete overhaul, a radical overhaul*. So *major* conveys that it is more of an overhaul than a plain overhaul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Overhaul* as a verb is not absolute. Dictionaries disagree on the extent implied by it, but all seem in concordance that it involves "extensive" repairs, usually including the dismantling of the object or system in question. Still, "extensive" itself is a relative term, which means there are degrees of *overhaul* implicit in the operation. If there are degrees, then a modifier such as *major* is simply a specifier, not a pleonasm.

Since the process of *dismantling* something is usually implicit in the word, we can extend the qualifier further. Are there relative degrees of dismantling? Sure there are. One could dismantle a car by removing the engine and transmission, for example. Or one could go further and remove the wheels, doors, and seats. And so on.

The point is, simply because a word implies something that may seem "complete" does not mean there are not relative states of completion. So think carefully before you brand a term as pleonasm. Even the idea of a "complete vacuum" is not redundant, since perfect vacuum is supposedly impossible in nature.

Even perhaps one of the most famous pleonasms of all, the one stylists point to when they want to hammer home the precept of brevity, is open to interpretation: Can we ever say something is "completely destroyed"? I think we can. Destruction may imply that something is ruined beyond use, but surely further destruction is possible. You can destroy (synonym: *ruin*) a computer by burning out its motherboard, or you can destroy it by smashing more of its components, putting it through an industrial shredder, dropping it into an outpouring of lava, or blowing it up with a quantity of dynamite. In each of these cases the computer may be destroyed, but some processes destroy it more than others. If you destroy it beyond what an overhaul might reasonably fix, you may be said to have *completely* destroyed it. Take that, style purists!

That said, we would all probably do well to avoid ladling on the modifiers. Most of the time you can say more with fewer words.

Answer (score -1):

Yes and no: In some cases it's part of a code used by auto mechanics. "Overhaul" means your bill will be in the hundreds of dollars - "Major Overhaul" means you're going to be paying for the mechanic's Caribbean vacation.